# Which primes $p$ divides $n^2+n-1$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

If $p$ is a prime such that $p | n^2+n-1$, then I would like to show that either $p = 5$ or $p \equiv \pm 1$ (mod $10$).

I have not had any success with this problem. I have tried to use the fact that if $p | n^2+n-1$, then $p \nmid n^2 + n = n(n+1) \Rightarrow p \nmid n$ and $p \nmid n+1$.

I also tried to use Legendre symbols by noting that $n^2 + n - 1 \equiv 0$ (mod $p$) $\Rightarrow n^2 \equiv 1-n $ (mod $p$) $\Rightarrow ((1-n)/p) = 1$ (where $(\cdot / \cdot)$ denotes Legendre symbols). I don't think this was a good idea since I don't even know whether gcd($1-n,p$) = 1.

I tried assuming that $p = 10k \pm 3$ and hoped that I could show that this implies $p \nmid n^2+n-1$, but I am still stuck.

Comment: Have you learned quadratic reciprocity?

Comment: Well, $n^2+n-1\equiv\pm1,5\bmod{10}$...

Comment: That is what I am having trouble showing. @DonThousand

Comment: Yes I am somewhat familiar with quadratic reciprocity @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @virreand Just test the $10$ cases...

Comment: Interestingly, every prime natural number $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{5}$ can be represented in infinitely many ways as $$p=a^2+ab-b^2,$$
where $a$ and $b$ are integers (or just positive integers).  For example, $11=3^2+3\cdot 2-2^2$, $19=4^2+4\cdot 3-3^2$, and $29=5^2+5\cdot 4-4^2$.  This is because $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}\right]$ is a real quadratic field with class number $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discriminant of your quadratic is $\Delta= 5$ so you are asking:  for which primes $p$ is $5$ a quadratic residue? Assume $p$ is odd and $\neq 5$.  Since $5\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ we can invoke quadratic reciprocity to conclude that $$\Bigg ( \frac 5p\Bigg)=\Bigg (\frac p5\Bigg )$$ which is $1\iff p\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 5$.

We remark that for an odd prime to be of the form $\pm 1 \pmod 5$ it must be of the form $\pm 1 \pmod {10}$ since $5k\pm 1$ odd $\implies k$ is even.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

We have that $p\mid n^2+n-1$ iff $p$ is odd and $p\mid 4n^2+4n-4=(2n+1)^2-5.$

So $5$ is a square modulo $p,$ or $\left(\frac 5 p\right)=1.$